# Paste clipboard HTML data and keep CSS and images

Tags: html, css, clipboard

I copy an wikipedia article consiting of images and text. I paste it in to div that is set to contenteditable="true". I can see the pasted material like it looks at wikipedia.

How can I save the content of that div and include the styling and the images now it is only text that I can save? Save it e.g. as an object that could be sent to the service.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PpaS8/)

html

```
<div class="inputdiv"contenteditable="true"> paste here </div>
```

Comment: isn't this what's cURL is for?

Comment: Save it to where? A webserver? What webserver, what technology?

Comment: Save it e.g. as an object that could be sent to the service.

Comment: What service? With the huge amount of possible frameworks and or external services that you might be using there is no way to tell how to process the contents of the div. Do you mean to submit it with a form? Or send it over with an ajax post?

Comment: I want to send it with an ajax post

Comment: That's something I can work with. Hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the contents of the div using `jQuery` and post it with an ajax request to the service. E.g:

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
      var html = $(".inputdiv").html();

        var jqxhr = $.post( "http://www.url-of-service.com", {input: html})
        .done(function() {
          alert( "success" );
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, errorMsg) {
            alert( "error: " + errorMsg);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PpaS8/1/

Make sure you put the correct url of the service instead of `http://www.url-of-service.com` and the correct key for the post var instead of `input:`.

Comment: and that includes the css?

Comment: No you'd have to download the CSS from the wikipedia server. I'm not sure if that's 100% possible with Javascript/jQuery.. I would suggest including the wikipedia css on the page where the contents of this div get outputted again. If that is legally allowed, I do not know. I'm no expert on that matter.

Comment: Another option is to write your own CSS to match that of wikipedia's.